# Subsetting of R data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have a rookie question on subsetting in R.

This is the function I have created. I'm trying to find the median weight in a particular day, from a list of files in my directory.

```
weightmedian <- function(directory, day){
  files <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)
  dat <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:5){
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files[i]))  
  }
  dat_subset <- subset(dat$Weight, dat$Day == day, select = c("Patient.Name", "Age", "Day"))
  median(dat_subset[, "Weight"], na.rm = T)
}
```

The problem I am facing is on this line:

> dat_subset <- subset(dat$Weight, dat$Day == day, select = c("Patient.Name", "Age", "Day"))

The error I receive after running through this code with weightmedian("diet_data", 15):

> Error in dat_subset[, "Weight"] : incorrect number of dimensions

However, when I replace the above mentioned line of code with this instead:

> dat_subset <- dat[which(dat[, "Day"] == day), ]

The code runs perfectly.

My question is, why am I faced with an incorrect dimensions error when the two subsetting methods are similar? Am I missing something here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `Subset` is only used to subset data.frames, yet you are using `subset(data$Weighht...` this is a vectior not a dataframe

Comment: oh dear. how should I have written it such that I can still use the subset function?

Comment: use `subset(data,...)`

Comment: thanks so much Onyambu!!! Got it! :D

Comment: Did it work?or not yet?

Comment: yes it worked! Thanks!